# mod_rewrite: periods from URI gone in the query string

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

**Problem**:
See examples below. When using mod_rewrite to put
"the URI part after the script name" into the query string (in any way),
the ending periods (.) of every "directory" are removed. (Apache 2.2.14 on win32.)

**Question**:
Is there any way to solve this or do I have to parse REQUEST_URI?

**Request** ("."s escaped):

```
http://localhost/simp.fcgi/fo%2eo%2e=12%2e3%2e/ba%2eh%2e%2e%2e/baz%2e?foo%2e=bar%2e

(Always get REQUEST_URI: /simp.fcgi/fo.o.=12.3./ba.h.../baz%2e?foo%2e=bar%2e)

RewriteRule ^simp.fcgi/(.*)$ simple.fcgi?qs=$1
Got      QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3/ba.h/baz
Expected QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3./ba.h.../baz.
      or QUERY_STRING: qs=fo%2eo%2e=12%2e3%2e/ba%2eh%2e%2e%2e/baz%2e

RewriteRule ^simp.fcgi/(.*)$ simple.fcgi?qs=$1 [NE]
Got      QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3/ba.h/baz
Expected QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3./ba.h.../baz.
      or QUERY_STRING: qs=fo%2eo%2e=12%2e3%2e/ba%2eh%2e%2e%2e/baz%2e

RewriteRule ^simp.fcgi/(.*)$ simple.fcgi?qs=$1 [QSA]
Got      QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3/ba.h/baz&foo%2e=bar%2e
Expected QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3./ba.h.../baz.&foo%2e=bar%2e
      or QUERY_STRING: qs=fo%2eo%2e=12%2e3%2e/ba%2eh%2e%2e%2e/baz%2e&foo%2e=bar%2e
```

**Request** ("."s not escaped):

```
http://localhost/simp.fcgi/fo.o.=12.3./ba.h.../baz.?foo.=bar.

(Always get REQUEST_URI: /simp.fcgi/fo.o.=12.3./ba.h.../baz%2e?foo.=bar.)

RewriteRule ^simp.fcgi/(.*)$ simple.fcgi?qs=$1 [QSA]
Got      QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3/ba.h/baz&foo.=bar.
Expected QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3./ba.h.../baz.&foo.=bar.

RewriteRule ^simp.fcgi/(.*)$ simple.fcgi?qs=$1
Got      QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3/ba.h/baz
Expected QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3./ba.h.../baz.

RewriteRule ^simp.fcgi/(.*)$ simple.fcgi?qs=$1 [NE]
Got      QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3/ba.h/baz
Expected QUERY_STRING: qs=fo.o.=12.3./ba.h.../baz.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the value from `THE_REQUEST` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /simp\.fcgi/([^?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^simp\.fcgi/ simple.fcgi?qs=%1 [QSA]
```

Comment: That works. It also works to use REQUEST_URI, which yields a bit simpler expression:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/simp\.fcgi/(.*)
RewriteRule ^simp\.fcgi/ simple.fcgi?qs=%1